# Is it possible to call a blazor-server function from browser

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Look at this **blazor-server** code:

```
@page "/test"

@if (check_if_user_is_allowed())
{
    <button @onclick="@(() => on_btn_click())">Click me</button>
}

@code{
    
    public async void on_btn_click()
    {
        if (!check_if_user_is_allowed() return ; // Necessary ?

        // Very sensitive code
    }
}
```

When an allowed user clicks on the button, the browser sends a message to server. I suppose this message contains "on_btn_click". I suppose this is possible to "capture" this message.

Is it possible for another user, which is not allowed, but knows the existence of "on_btn_click" function, to forge and send a message to server in order to call "on_btn_click" function ?

In other words, should i double-check by calling "check_if_user_is_allowed" in on_btn_click ? Or this is not necessary ?

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer is that your backend should always double check and enforce security.

Comment: Yes i will double check but i want to know if it is possible...

Comment: Is this page authorized? If yes, and if you are using a blazor server, I don't think it is possible. Because in that case, the user will have to perform a man-in-the-middle attack I guess.

Comment: The page is authorized. What i want to check is a special feature on the page for specific users